# Converting currency (BTC to Nok), unsure how to approach it with math in php

Tags: php, math

Basically, I'm trying to convert Nok to BTC and BTC to Nok.

I have to Nok to BTC working, I'm just having a little issue with the BTC to Nok...

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php
public function increase_by_percent($btc) {


    $math = $btc/10;

    return $btc + $math;
    //current BTC Rate + 10%
}

public function get_current_btc() {
    /** Gets current Nok value of BTC , Result = Nok Currency = 1BTC. */     
    $json = file_get_contents("http://www.data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCNOK/ticker_fast");
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    //var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
    return $obj["return"]["last_local"]["value"];
}

public function convert_to_btc($nok /** How much NOK */, $btc /** How much BTC is             worth*/) {
    /** gives them the estimated amount of BTC they will get based upon how much Nok    they have, and the set value of the BTC */
    $newbtc = $nok/$btc;

    return $newbtc;
}
/** vvv This is where i'm mainky stuck at */
public function convert_to_nok($btc /** How much BTC */) {
    $btc_price = $this->increase_by_percent($this->get_current_btc()); //            = "our" BTC price 

    $newnok = "";
    return $newnok;
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do basically get how much BTC they want (like they type in 0.0005),and it will convert it to Nok currency based upon the string `$btc_price`

Thanks again. I'm just a bit confused on the math. Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: Is it math question specifically or it has something to do with php? If the latter - what are the math formulas you cannot convert to php? Assuming you have a number `42`, how would you increase it by `10%` on a piece of paper?

Comment: No its not the php, the php works fine. I'm able to increase the numbers by 10% already. I included the php for people to see how it works. The problem is converting it to Nok (A different currency, which is in $btc_price, and $btc_price (nok)) = 1BTC)

Comment: what is the question then?

Comment: When you have a conversion rate, you multiply to go in one direction, divide to go in the other direction.

Comment: This is grade school arithmetic, isn't it?

Comment: I know this is basic school math, I know how to divide, Its just how to get it to convert to Nok correctly. From BTC. I don't need to code or anything, I just need to confirm the Math I need to use (i.e x / y = currency converted)

Answer (score 0):

If your conversion rate *r* is the price of one BTC, expressed in NOK (which seems to be the direction your URL takes), then you convert between an amount of *n* NOC resp. *b* BTC using these formulas:

```
n = b*r
b = n/r
```

If you take average conversion fees into account, you use the smaller `buy` value when multiplying but the larger `sell` value when dividing.